# Go protobuff import issue

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protobuf-go

wanted to be able to read meshtastic protobuf packets. I used [buf.buid](https://buf.build/meshtastic/protobufs/sdks/main) to generate the SDK. Then I imported them to my mqtt.go file:

```
package main

import (
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"io"
"log"
"os"
"os/signal"
"strings"
"sync"
"syscall"

mqttProto "buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go"
mqtt "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
"google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
)
```

However when I try to run with go run mqtt.go I obtain this error:

```
no required module provides package buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go; to add it: go get buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go
```

When I try to use go get buf.build/... I get an empty output and the problem remains.

I also tried to run go mod tidy and I got this error:

```
go: finding module for package buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go
go: router imports buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go: module buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go@latest found (v1.32.0-20240228025038-216ffc09a4e9.1), but does not contain package buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go
```

I also tried do run go clean -modcache and it didn't help. Any idea on how to fix the problem? thanks

Comment: Are there any go files in `buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go`? Or are the Go files in sub-directories you'd need to import?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. It's the first time I tried to use protobuff. What I did was just run go get buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go@latest that is the command that buf.build tells me to run. According to the documentation, this should just work. The command didn't add any folder or file to my workspace

Comment: `go get` adds a dedepndency to the `go.mod` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at what the go module actually contains by `go get`ting it and then checking its content in the module cache. The module cache is located in `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` (on mac that defaults to `~/go/pkg/mod`). From there you should be able to navigate to the module by following the folders of the import path.

In this case it turns out there are no Go files in the module itself, just the `go.mod` file and a `LICENSE`. All Go files are in the sub-folder `meshtastic`.

Meaning the import path should be:

```
import mqttProto "buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go/meshtastic"
```

Making that change should fix the issue.

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thank you very much for the fast response!

Answer (score 1):

example

```golang
    package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
    
        "buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go/meshtastic"
        mqtt "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
        "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
    )
    
    func main() {
        _ = proto.Int32(1)
        _ = mqtt.DummyToken{}
        _ = meshtastic.QueueStatus{}
        _ = meshtastic.AdminMessage{}
        fmt.Println("liber test")
    }
```

```bash
  cat go.mod
```

```golang
    module proto


    go 1.21.6
    
    require (
        buf.build/gen/go/meshtastic/protobufs/protocolbuffers/go v1.28.1-20240228025038-216ffc09a4e9.4
        github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang v1.4.3
        google.golang.org/protobuf v1.32.0
    )
    
    require (
        github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.9 // indirect
        github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.5.0 // indirect
        golang.org/x/net v0.8.0 // indirect
        golang.org/x/sync v0.1.0 // indirect
    )
```

[image]